# Different storyboard for iPhone 7 and 7 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, xcode8

I have a circle in the middle which we called a bubble.
Now when I change in the storyboard the view as to iPhone 7 it looks like this:
[image: iPhone7 in iPhone7 view]

But when I change it to view as iPhone 7 Plus it looks like this

[image: iPhone7 in iPhone7 plus view]

The circle is not circular anymore. How is that possible when I didn't change anything else but the view as? Does this view as actually update the storyboard?

To make the circle I use the following line of code:

```
self.bubble?.layer.cornerRadius = (self.bubble?.frame.height)! / 2
```

If yes does apple select the storyboard based on the iPhone I install my app on?

Comment: Your label probably does not have a fixed aspect ratio but a fixed bottom size constraint!?

Comment: Are you setting the circle programatically?

Comment: @User511 Yes I use self.bubble?.layer.cornerRadius = (self.bubble?.frame.height)! / 2

Comment: Just set the width and height fixed constraint for self.bubble. It will work of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maybe the view width is not equal to its height.**

> Add an aspect ratio constraint between view width and height.
>
> **Or**
>
> You can set a fixed width and height constraint as @User511
>   mentioned. Whatever, that suits you.

Also, you could be setting the `cornerRadius` before the view takes its final shape.  Try to move the following to `viewWillAppear` or to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method:

```
self.bubble?.layer.cornerRadius = (self.bubble?.frame.height)! / 2
```

Comment: I have an aspect ratio constraint on it and it looks OK when I run it on an iPhone 7 plus.

Comment: Are you sure that this constrant does not get broken at runtime?

Comment: I measured the width and height of your bubble on the simulator. looks fine. It looks like you set the corner radius before the view takes its final shape. try the willappear or didlayout methods.

Comment: yes you were right that was the problem I moved the setting of the corner radius now to viewDidLayoutSubviews and now it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add autolayout constraint to your circle. Aspect ratio 1:1 will help you
[image]